# How to return multiple possible types in C# .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a WebApi with .Net Core. I was trying to implement a simple sign-up control logic in my DataAccess layer. Basically when a user sends a request to sign up my app, the service called "CheckCredentials" is going to control the Db and check wheter is some information in the request that must be unique is exists in the Db or not. If it is, it supposed to return something with a type named "CCFeedback", if it's not exists in Db then the return type should be the information which is just created "User".

My question is, is it possible to make a method to have multiple Type arguments which returns the corresponding Type coming from DataAccess layer ?

Something like this:

```
// This is from Business Logic layer
// Right now giving me this error 'the non generic type task cannot be used with type arguments'
public async Task<User || CCFeedback> CreateUser(User user)
        {
            CCFeedback DAFeedback = await _UserRepository.CheckCredentials(user);
            switch (DAFeedback.property)
            {
                case "UO":
                    throw new Exception("Username already taken!");
                case "PO":
                    throw new Exception("You entered a registered phone!");
                case "UP":
                    throw new Exception("Both Username and Phone are already registered!");
                case null:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return await _UserRepository.CreateUser(user);
        }

// This is from DataAccess layer
public async Task<CCFeedback> CheckCredentials(User user)
        {
            using (var rnTrainingDbContext = new RNTrainingDbcontext())
            {
                CCFeedback feedback;

                var entityUsernameCheck = await rnTrainingDbContext.Users
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(entity => entity.Username == user.Username);
                var entityPhoneCheck = await rnTrainingDbContext.Users
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(entity => entity.Phone == user.Phone);

                if((entityUsernameCheck != null) && (entityPhoneCheck != null))
                {
                    feedback = new CCFeedback {
                        property = "UP",  // UP -> Both username and phone already exists in DB
                        isValid = false
                    };
                    return feedback;
                } else if ((entityUsernameCheck != null))
                {
                    feedback = new CCFeedback {
                        property = "UO",  // UO -> Only username already exists in DB
                        isValid = false
                    };
                    return feedback;
                } else if ((entityPhoneCheck != null))
                {
                    feedback = new CCFeedback {
                        property = "PO",  // PO -> Only Phone already exists in DB
                        isValid = false
                    };
                    return feedback;
                } else
                {
                    feedback = new CCFeedback {
                        property = null,
                        isValid = true
                    };
                    return feedback;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My aim is to replace the Exceptions with proper responses because right now server sends 500 (Internal Server Error) code with explanations i gave.

CreateUser must return a value with the type "User" only if the credentials avaliable for creation, otherwise it must return a value with the type "CCFeedback" which refers to which properties already exist in Db.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the User value into a result class. Something that can hold both the successful state (the user object) as well as errors.

Comment: no this isn't possible. C# is a *statically typed* language. Every object has exactly *one single type*. How would you ever be sure what type of object you may recieve from an API otherwise? You'd need some annoying if/else switch all around your client-code to handle the possible cases. This is to prevent you shoot into your own foot. But you can do it anyway using `dynamic`, which will completely bypass the compiler.

Comment: You're looking for discriminated unions, which C# doesn't have. There are some libraries which provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebApi uses JSON to communicate with the client. JSON does not contain class names. If your web service returns `{ "message": "x" }` and both `User` and `CCFeedback` happen to have a `Message` property, how is the client supposed to know which type of result has been returned?

There are a few alternative approaches you can use.

- The simplest would be to create a new `CreateUserResult` class with both a `User` and a `Feedback` property, and the convention that exactly one of them is non-null.
- Alternatively, you could return a different HTTP status code (e.g. 400 instead of 200) and return a different object in case of an error. ASP.NET Core provides a built-in way to do that by [throwing a HttpResponseException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling).

Comment: Okey now i'm creating a Model called "CUFeedback" which contains both User and CCFeedback properties. But i'm defining these models in the Abstract folder of DataAccess layer. I have two files called CCFeedback and CUFeedback in Abstract folder now. Where is the best place to create these models in ?

Comment: @caliskanata: I would personally put it in the folder/namespace where I store my DTOs (data transfer objects), i.e., where I put all the objects that are part of the official "contract" of my web service.

Answer (score 0):

no this isn't possible. C# is a *statically typed* language. Every object has exactly *one single type*. You surely won't expect `2 + 2` to ever return something different than a `number`, will you? Of course you *could* handle the "normal" case and the error-case with an HTTP-200-result and provide a message in the error-case. However I think there are better ways to do that. Usually when receiving a 200-response I don't expect to further investigate into potential message-objects to know if the request was *really* successful.

Which makes me assume you're effectivly mixing two things that exclude one another: one being what the server returns on a successful request, and the other what it returns in an error-case. There's no way a server can be successfull but with an error-message.

Easiest way is to just throw an exception upon an error, which will cause your request to produce a 500 error. You can further customize the response-status being sent from your server, e.g. by sending a 4xx-error instead or whatever.

Another route you can go is using `dynamic` for your functions return-type. Now a client can call *any* member on the returned value:

```
dynamic DAFeedback = await _UserRepository.CheckCredentials(user);
DAFeedback.ThisCompiles();
DAFeedback.AsWellAsThisOne(1);
```

As you can see this completely bypasses every compiler-checks, which is he entire point of type-safety in the first place. So I don't thoink this is what you really want here.